# shared library issues while migrating from CodeSourcery armel to Linaro armhf compiler

Tags: codesourcery, linaro

I am migrating a Xilinx Zynq board from from the CodeSourcery armel (gnueabi) toolchain (from Vivado 2015.2) to a Linaro armhf, so we could instal Debian/Ubuntu armhf (gnueabihf).

While attempting to `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` a shared library, we get the next error from `dlerror()`:

```
/.../controller.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv119__pointer_type_infoE
```

The issue is present if the Linaro toolchain is used while software compiled with the CodeSourcery toolchain works properly.

I checked both libraries for the reported symbol and it is present in both:

```
$ grep -r cxxabiv119__pointer_type_info .
./controller.so.armel.simbols:U _ZTVN10__cxxabiv119__pointer_type_infoE
./controller.so.armhf.simbols:U _ZTVN10__cxxabiv119__pointer_type_infoE
```

It seems that if controller.so contains only C code (no C++ code) it works properry with Linaro. But the difference might be something else than the language used.

Regards,
Iztok Jeras

Comment: This is the detail on how the library was opened:

    app->handle = dlopen(app_file, RTLD_LAZY);

Comment: Don't use grep; use `objdump` to list the symbols. You may find that the broken library uses the symbol but doesn't define it.

Answer (score 0):

There was no simple answer to this problem, in the end I switched from cross compiling to a native compiler inside a QEMU emulated ARM environment. This was suggested by various Raspberry PI users. On the other hand every cross compiler solution just unearthed a new set of problems.